# How to only build the wiki-page without building java doc with maven?

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

We use the following command to build javadoc and wiki-page with maven:

```
-e -s clean site
```

The wiki-page is in format *.apt and it's written in doxia. Here is the code structure of wiki-page:

```
+- src/
   +- site/
      +- apt/
      |  +- index.apt
      |
      +- site.xml
```

Is there a command so that I can build the wiki pages without building javadoc? Because it lasts too long to build all javadocs for the whole project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to start a single goal / execution in maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159002/how-to-start-a-single-goal-execution-in-maven)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to investigate the config options of the site mojo itself.
It has switches for preventing the generation of certain reports.
Override the default settings for Site by including the following in your pom
build/plugins section :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <generateReports>false</generateReports>
        <generateSitemap>false</generateSitemap>
        <generateProjectInfo>false</generateProjectInfo>
         .... etc.
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want here to configure the reports being generated then displayed on the site.

Maven site plugin should only generate reports for report tasks of plugins specified in the `<reporting>` section.
So check whether the javadoc plugin is specified in the reporting section, and remove it if it is.

Have a look there: [Configuring Reports](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/configuring-reports.html) for more precise detail about reports and plugin report goals fine tuning.